# Git release merging strategy

Tags: git

In our project we have 3 branches, `master`, `release` and `production`. Where `master` is our development branch. The idea is that the `release` branch is not persistent. I.e. it will be created for the purpose of making a release and deleted after the release has been merged into the `production` branch.

At the end of a sprint we create a new `release` branch based of `master` and let the team PR review this `release` branch for approval.

However, it might be that during the approval some commits that were made on `master` (and that are now also on the `release` branch) should actually not be merged into the `production` branch.

E.g. the following commits have been made on `master`:

```
commit-1
commit-2
commit-3
```

After creating the `release` branch we have the same commits on the `release` branch but maybe `commit-2` should not be released yet.

```
commit-1
commit-2  <- remove for the 'release` branch
commit-3
```

How can `commit-2` safely be removed from the `release` branch but still remain on the `master` branch to be merged in a future release?

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) is for. Just revert `commit-2` directly on `release`, to negate it. Effectively you have a created a new commit whose sole purpose is to undo the effect of an existing commit.

The negation commit appears only on `release` so it affects only `release`. This is also nice historically; you are actually describing, with your history, what the procedure was for forming this release.

Mini-example. I start by creating your three commits (on master):

```
$ echo a > a.txt
$ git add .; git commit -ma
$ echo b > b.txt
$ git add .; git commit -mb
$ echo c > c.txt
$ git add .; git commit -mc
```

Now I make the release branch. Realizing that commit `b` should not be part of this release, I suppress it by reverting it:

```
$ git branch release
$ git switch release
$ git revert 883ae
Removing b.txt
```

Here's the situation:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --all
* 022f96f (HEAD -> release) Revert "b"
* 6a6acfe (master) c
* 883ae8f b
* a186a8a a
```

OK. On release, how do our files look:

```
$ ls
a.txt   c.txt
```

As you can see, the effect of `883ae8f`, which created `b.txt`, has been erased from the release branch. But meanwhile, master is unaffected:

```
$ git switch master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
a.txt   b.txt   c.txt
```

Comment: Ah nice. So, this also means that when I create a new release branch after the previous release was merged into master that it would contain the `b.txt` commit?

Comment: Oh, one more question, the negation commit will appear on my production branch when release is merged into production? If so, I guess that would be less desirable...

Comment: "this also means" Obviously. Using my example, try it: switch to master and make another release branch (perhaps after deleting the existing one, or give it a different name). The `b` commit is still in master so it is on this new release branch.

Comment: "the negation commit will appear on my production branch when release is merged into production" I wouldn't see why. The only new thing that will appear _on_ the production branch when release is merged into it is the merge commit. A commit from the release branch is not going to magically wander into the main line of the production branch! And as I said, to the extent that the reversion is reachable in the history, that's actually _good_, because it describes so perfectly what happened. You could erase the history if you really wanted to, but I don't recommend it. History is good!

Comment: OK. I did some playing around with the scenario that you describe. However, after creating my release and merging it into production (rebase & merge), when I then create a new release (new release branch based of master), the PR for this new release branch lists all commits (i.e. the commit for a, b and c) whereas I would expected to only see the "b" commit that was previously not merged into production (i.e. the difference). As I understand it correctly is that my release will be an ever growing list of commits that included all commits from the beginning of time?

Comment: That seems a completely different matter? That has nothing to do with the question you are asking here about removing one commit. It is a consequence of your overall strategy, which you said you have already adopted.